# D3 nodes group/bundle and cycles between nodes

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, force-layout

I have little problem with D3 force diagram. I´m using prepared demo with grouping nodes by group name. This is [demo](http://bl.ocks.org/GerHobbelt/3071239)
I have problem with function network(), where are mapping links. In my dataset i have link which are connected in both directions, it means that between two nodes can be cycle. In this method are cycles removed. I´m totally lost how to repair this function.

This is what i need: both direction links...

[image: This is what i need]

Problematic code:

```
// constructs the network to visualize
function network(data, prev, index, expand) {
  expand = expand || {};
  var gm = {},    // group map
      nm = {},    // node map
      lm = {},    // link map
      gn = {},    // previous group nodes
      gc = {},    // previous group centroids
      nodes = [], // output nodes
      links = []; // output links

  // process previous nodes for reuse or centroid calculation
  if (prev) {
    prev.nodes.forEach(function(n) {
      var i = index(n), o;
      if (n.size > 0) {
        gn[i] = n;
        n.size = 0;
      } else {
        o = gc[i] || (gc[i] = {x:0,y:0,count:0});
        o.x += n.x;
        o.y += n.y;
        o.count += 1;
      }
    });
  }

  // determine nodes
  for (var k=0; k<data.nodes.length; ++k) {
    var n = data.nodes[k],
        i = index(n),
        l = gm[i] || (gm[i]=gn[i]) || (gm[i]={group:i, size:0, nodes:[]});

    if (expand[i]) {
      // the node should be directly visible
      nm[n.name] = nodes.length;
      nodes.push(n);
      if (gn[i]) {
        // place new nodes at cluster location (plus jitter)
        n.x = gn[i].x + Math.random();
        n.y = gn[i].y + Math.random();
      }
    } else {
      // the node is part of a collapsed cluster
      if (l.size == 0) {
        // if new cluster, add to set and position at centroid of leaf nodes
        nm[i] = nodes.length;
        nodes.push(l);
        if (gc[i]) {
          l.x = gc[i].x / gc[i].count;
          l.y = gc[i].y / gc[i].count;
        }
      }
      l.nodes.push(n);
    }
  // always count group size as we also use it to tweak the force graph strengths/distances
    l.size += 1;
  n.group_data = l;
  }

  for (i in gm) { gm[i].link_count = 0; }

  // determine links
  for (k=0; k<data.links.length; ++k) {
    var e = data.links[k],
        u = index(e.source),
        v = index(e.target);
  if (u != v) {
    gm[u].link_count++;
    gm[v].link_count++;
  }
    u = expand[u] ? nm[e.source.name] : nm[u];
    v = expand[v] ? nm[e.target.name] : nm[v];
    var i = (u<v ? u+"|"+v : v+"|"+u),
        l = lm[i] || (lm[i] = {source:u, target:v, size:0});
    l.size += 1;
  }
  for (i in lm) { links.push(lm[i]); }

  return {nodes: nodes, links: links};
}
```